# COMPILAR C EN VISUAL STUDIO CODE

Tags: c, visual-studio

Hola he instalado el visual studio para poder programar en C y C++ ya instale tambien el MINGW 64 guiada de un video de YouTube pero cuando intento compilar mi hola mundo me aparece el siguiente mensaje

```
hola.exe : El término 'hola.exe' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si 
escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ hola.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (hola.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 

Suggestion [3,General]: No se encontró el comando hola.exe, pero existe en la ubicación actual. Windows PowerShell no carga comandos de la ubicación actual de forma predeterminada. Si confía en este comando, escriba ".\hola.exe". Vea "get-help about_Command_Precedence" para obtener información más detallada.
```

Nose que mas hacer ayuda porfavor...

Comment: Dónde te sale eso? en la consola de PowerShell cuando escribes "hola.exe" y pulsas ENTER? Te está diciendo lo que tienes que hacer: Ejecutar ".\hola.exe" y no "hola.exe".

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad¡¡¡ :')